# Processing toolbox: random points inside polygon Parameter meaning

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

I am using the **random points inside polygon Tool from the QGIS-processing toolbox**. Unfortunately I dont know want the following parameter **Exponent** means.
Also I would like to know a little bit about the optional usage of a **transformation curve**. Obviosly in "default usage" (unticked) there is a linear relationship. Any cases where the usage of applying a transformation curve is useful?

The documentation https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorcreation.html#random-points-inside-polygons does not provide any hints to EXPONENT and the usage of the TRANSFORMATION CURVE.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this explanation for the scale_exp function which states what the exponent does.

> Exponent - A positive value (greater than 0), which dictates the way input values are mapped to the output range. Large exponents will cause the output values to ‘ease in’, starting slowly before accelerating as the input values approach the domain maximum. Smaller exponents (less than 1) will cause output values to ‘ease out’, where the mapping starts quickly but slows as it approaches the domain maximum.

It can be found in the QGIS help pages with some examples here:

https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/expression.html#scale-exp